# Source Generator - File path the source code is located

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

I have Project A that uses a DLL with Source Generator B. When the Source Generator runs, I need to know the file path that A was located.

My Source Generator implements `ISourceGenerator`. `GeneratorExecutionContext` doesn't seem to contain anything relevant to file path, as far as I can tell.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of mucking about in the properties of `GeneratorExecutionContext` I finally located the caller's file path somewhere. It's easiest to just put it in an Extension method.

```
/// <summary>Gets the file path the source generator was called from.</summary>
/// <param name="context">The context of the Generator's Execute method.</param>
/// <returns>The file path the generator was called from.</returns>
public static string GetCallingPath(this GeneratorExecutionContext context)
{
    return context.AnalyzerConfigOptions.GlobalOptions.TryGetValue("build_property.projectdir", out var result) ? result : null;
}
```